# How can I capture & authorize paypal payments without using setReturnUrl

Tags: java, paypal

I'm trying to accept payments for my application using PayPal. I have it set up where I can pay the express-checkout; But once I pay the amount I get redirected so I can authorize the payment, but i'm not using a web server, How I can disable url redirects and just capture the payment as soon as they pay?

```
        RedirectUrls redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
        redirectUrls.setCancelUrl("example.com/");
        redirectUrls.setReturnUrl("example.com/");
        payment.setRedirectUrls(redirectUrls);
```

I need to disable these, so instead of redirecting it thats on the paypal page

Actual Results are `example.com/paymentId=PAY-SIMP&token=EC-SIMP&PayerID=SIMP`

When my expected results should not redirect to example.com, but stay on paypals website.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using a server, then wherever you are generating the payment is where you need to handle the return after the customer authorizes the transaction at PayPal, and execute the transaction.

Comment: How would I get the return url? once I make the createdPayment

Comment: It needs to return somewhere, either to the JS (onAuthorize function?) or to an app deeplink or to a webserver url. And then you need to execute the payment.

Comment: I'm not using JS, Im using java and I haven't seen anything.

Comment: Im not using an android app; that has no info on what i'm trying to do

Comment: You are not using a web server, you are using java, but you are not using android.

What exactly are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the other comments, my understanding is you have no mobile app, just a Java client-side desktop app, and no corresponding server (or at least no web server, as you say)

PayPal is an ecommerce payment service that provides no SDKs that are intended or useful from such a Java desktop application. So, you should get rid of whatever you’ve written so far.

Without any web server nor android/mobile app, the question really becomes: “I have a desktop application. What it the best way to accept PayPal payments with no web presence?”

And there are two reasonable alternatives:

1. PayPal Payments Standard, opening an in-app browser or the system’s
   default browser, with a web link such as: 
   https://www.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=your_paypal_account@somedomain.com&item_name=some%20item%20or%20service&amount=100&currency_code=USD
2. A client-side integration of Smart Payment Buttons, using a local
   HTML file loaded in a web browser -- using code similar to the
   following skeleton demo:
   https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

A potential third alternative would be to host a micro-webserver using some port on localhost, so as to handle the return of a full SDK.